# Numeric or value error in stored procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Hello i have an oracle database and i am trying to add a procedure to select driver based on the input however i get this error message Numeric or value error
If i remove the varchar2 outputs from the procedure and try in plsql no problem happens
[image]

```
OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand();
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.CommandText = "SelectDrive";

            command.Parameters.Add("LicenseNumber", OracleDbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.Input);
            command.Parameters["LicenseNumber"].Value = Int32.Parse(bunifuMaterialTextbox2.Text);

            command.Parameters.Add("FirstNamee", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Output);
            command.Parameters.Add("LastNamee", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Output);
            command.Parameters.Add("ContactNumberr", OracleDbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.Output);


            int r = command.ExecuteNonQuery();




create or replace
PROCEDURE "SELECTDRIVE" 
 (LicenseNumber in number, FirstNamee out VARCHAR2, LastNamee out VARCHAR2, ContactNumberr out NUMBER)
as
begin

select d.firstname, d.lastname, d.contactnumber 
into   FirstNamee , LastNamee , ContactNumberr
from   Driver d
where LicenseNumber=d.license;
end;
```

any idea?

Comment: Where in your procedure code do you think you are using an input parameter?

Comment: Can you provide ddl for Driver table? It seems that _driver.license_ or _driver.contactnumber_ is non-numeric value

Comment: As you can see i am using it in the where condition in the procedure @DanBracuk

Comment: you can find it here https://pastebin.com/egzHw5kf @mkuligowski

Comment: Try using [`%TYPE`](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/type_attribute.htm), change `(LicenseNumber in number, FirstNamee out VARCHAR2, LastNamee out VARCHAR2, ContactNumberr out NUMBER)` to `(LicenseNumber in Driver.License%TYPE, FirstNamee out Driver.FirstName%TYPE, LastNamee out Driver.LastName%TYPE, ContactNumberr out Driver.ContactNumbe%TYPE)` that is. That will ensure the variables' types match the ones from the table. An issue there is out of the picture then.

Comment: same problem exists @stickybit

Comment: Then it's likely, that the types you are using for `command.Parameters.Add()` cause the problem. E.g. `DRIVER.CONTACTNUMBER` is a `NUMBER(11,0)` but  you're assigning an `OracleDbType.Int32`. An `INTEGER` is a `NUMBER(38, 0)`, so a `NUMBER(11,0)`  is too short. Try either changing the types in the table or in your assignments.

Comment: @stickybit the problem is in the firsname and lastname if i remove them from the procedure and leave contactnumber only it works so i dont think its something to do with contactnumber?

Comment: Based on the information given I don't see how `firstname` or `lastname` could be the problem. Your previous post with the DDL (https://stackoverflow.com/q/50090915/2091410) has the `LICENSE` column as `NUMBER(10)` and the `CONTACTNUMBER` column as `NUMBER(11)`. Both can exceed an `Int32`, which has a maximum value of 2,147,483,647. Try using `Int64`/`long` instead.

Comment: @EdGibbs i changed the columns to NUMBER with no precision already and still the same problem happens

Comment: `NUMBER` with no precision defaults to `NUMBER(38)` so that's even larger. Did you try changing to `Int64` in the c# code? That's the only potential issue I see with what you've posted in the questions: I'm pretty sure you'd get the ORA-06502 if the `contactnumberr` OUT parameter came back with a value > 2,147,483,647.